# How to show rounded value in input box but use actual unrounded value

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

```
<input type="text"
name="coefficient"
id="variable"
maxlength="10"
value="<fmt:formatNumber type="number" minFractionDigits="4" value="${coefficientValue}"
/>"/>
```

In the above input box i am getting the coefficient value like "0.0098764" , to display it upto 4 decimal places , i am formatting the value.
now when i want to save this value in the database again, i want the actual value      "coefficientValue" to save , and not the rounded off value.

I want that rounded off value to be displayed on screen  but actual value of the input should remain the same.

how can i have multiple values of an input box i.e. different value and different display.

Kindly help.

Comment: If you put it in an `<input>`, users might change the value. What do you want to submit in this case? The original (unrounded) value or the user input? You might add a `<input type="hidden">` field for the unrounded value, so you can decide after submitting what to do with which.

Comment: i have over 100 input boxes, then also , i have to use hidden fields for each??

Comment: A better approach might be to add request scoped beans for all unrounded values. This way, you need not change your JSP and the values would not be transmitted to the browser and back.

Answer (score 1):

U should add to this form 1 more input - type hidden, which will store actual value .
Hope it helps !

Comment: i have input boxes in large number, so i am looking for a better way instead of using hidden inputs for each

Comment: Suggestion: you could use just one <input hidden> and in its value you can put a json object which has entries for all of the desired textboxes.
E.g. <input type="hidden" value="{coeficient = 0.0098764, value2 = 33, etc = 'etc'}" />